# How to install cmake from source but without GUI(X11)

Tags: embedded, cmake

I want to build some packages inside embedded system (I don't require GUI). It it lack of memory, so there is no GUI.  But, some packages which use cmake.  And cmake force me to use X11. I don't require the QT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure `cmake`'s source-tree for build have you tried to use:

```
./configure --no-qt-gui
```

. It works for me.