# CMake Installation Error in Bootstrapping Step

Tags: linux, cmake, cmake-gui, cmake-language

I am trying to install CMake on our institutional server using a Linux command line. I am experiencing errors after the bootstrapping step and I get this error message:

CMake Error at /home/<my_name>/anaconda3/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:9 (message):
Failed to find "GL/gl.h" in

I tried looking for ways to install the missing file but it requires a "sudo" command which our server does not permit us to do.

Comment: Try building cmake without GUI. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033436/how-to-install-cmake-from-source-but-without-guix11